# Array of objects to object with keys JSON

Tags: javascript, json

This is the data recived from an API Call

```
[
    {
        "id": "id1",
        "data": "text"
    },
    {
        "id": "id2",
        "data": "text"
    }
]
```

How could i get the JSON data to look like this?

```
{
    "id1": {
        "data": "text"
    },
    "id2": {
        "data": "text"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array#reduce`

```js
var data = [ { "id": "id1", "data": "text" }, { "id": "id2", "data": "text" } ],
    result = data.reduce((r,{id,data}) => (r[id] = {data}, r), {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)<sup>a</sup> and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)<sup>b</sup> with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)<sup>c</sup> for the new  properties with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)<sup>d</sup>, [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)<sup>e</sup> and [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)<sup>f</sup>.

```
Object.assign(...array.map(({ id, data }) => ({ [id]: { data } })))
aaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbccccccccc  dddddddddddd        eeee    ffff
```

```js
var array = [{ id: "id1", data: "text" }, { id: "id2", data: "text" }],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(({ id, data }) => ({ [id]: { data } })));
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

use lodash `groupBy`

```
var a = [
        {
            "id": "id1",
            "data": "text"
        },
        {
            "id": "id2",
            "data": "text"
        }
    ]
_.groupBy(a, 'id')
```

result

```
{
    "id1": {
        "data": "text"
    },
    "id2": {
        "data": "text"
    }
}
```

or you can use this also

```
a.reduce((acc, item) => {
   acc[item.id] = item;
   return acc;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the two, which ever you find simpler.

```js
var arr = [
    {
        "id": "id1",
        "data": "text"
    },
    {
        "id": "id2",
        "data": "text"
    }
];

var obj = {};
arr.forEach(o => {
 obj[o.id] = {
  data: o.data
 }
})

console.log(obj);
```

```js
var arr = [
    {
        "id": "id1",
        "data": "text"
    },
    {
        "id": "id2",
        "data": "text"
    }
];

var obj = {};
for (const item of arr) {
 obj[item.id] = {
  data: item.data
 }
}

console.log(obj);
```